# Customize UIBarButtonItem with uitoolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to create a fully customize `UIToolbar` which contains 2 fully customized buttons.
Each of the button's width should be 50% of the toolbar width.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *ToolBar;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

button.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-10,self.ToolBar.frame.size.height-2);
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
[button setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
UIBarButtonItem *MsgButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];
[MsgButton setTitle:@"Msg"];

UIButton *button2 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-10,self.ToolBar.frame.size.height-2);
button2.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button2.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
[button2 setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
UIBarButtonItem *RelationButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button2];

self.ToolBar.items=@[MsgButton,RelationButton];
}
```

[screen shot](http://www.dhuocang.com/screen.png) this a screenshot of how it looks on my pc now.

Here are the problems:

1. How to removed the space on the left and the space between 2 buttons
2. I tried to display some text on the button it was not working.
3. If it is possible, can I only display a border on left or right of a button?

Comment: Check this out. I have manage this space in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475796/uibarbutton-item-on-screen-edge-in-ios-8-when-used-in-standalone-view/26479942#26479942

Comment: For your first question: You should alter this code in your snippet to achieve the change you want: `self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Try This

```
 UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    button.frame =CGRectMake(-15, 0, self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-20,self.ToolBar.frame.size.height-2);
    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    button.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    [button setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    UIButton *button2 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame=CGRectMake(self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-35, 0, self.ToolBar.frame.size.width/2-20,self.ToolBar.frame.size.height-2);
    button2.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    button2.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    [button2 setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    UIView *barView = [[UIView alloc] init];
     barView.frame = self.ToolBar.frame ;
    [barView addSubview:button];
    [barView addSubview:button2];
    UIBarButtonItem *RelationButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:barView];

   self.ToolBar.items=@[RelationButton];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However i found out that for buttton frame width,i set it to self.toolbar.frame.size.width/2-5 fit my appp screen perferctly. In addtion, is there anyway that i can only add a border on right or left?