# How to change distance between UINavigationBarButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I set two navigation bar buttons, and there is a space between it, how can I change this space to set buttons closer to each other?
I've tried to add third button with minus width, Here the code

```
self.editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Edit.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editAction:)];
self.callButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
spacer.width = -30;

NSArray *buttons = @[self.editButton, spacer, self.callButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

But it is not working; Any suggessions?

Comment: Use UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace in spacer initialization.

Comment: Take a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475796/uibarbutton-item-on-screen-edge-in-ios-8-when-used-in-standalone-view/26479942#26479942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                  target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -16;// it was -6 in iOS 6
[self.navigationItem rightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer, requriedButton/*this will be the button which u actually need*/, nil] animated:NO];
```

hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the style `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` and add it to the buttons array.